# Alternative encryption algorithm

Tags: aes, serpent, twofish

I need a alternative encryption alcorithm to AES. It shouldn't be AES, Twofish or Serpent and it must be very strong. I dont care about the performance.

Comment: What properties do you need? ChaCha is enjoying increased popularity, but being a stream cipher it's not suitable for every application. Depending on the application, authenticated encryption may be a better choice than plain encryption.

Comment: Why should it not be AES, Twofish, or Serpent?

Comment: Because of US algorithms are suspected to have backdoors.

Comment: You could probably do better encrypt your message with marker and decrypt with X-ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Camellia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_%28cipher%29) perhaps? NESSIE (EU) and CRYPTREC (Japan) both endorse it.

Your requirements are brief and mysterious so it's difficult to give further suggestions.